# MYSQL Foreign key error with workbench export

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables both with a couple foreign keys. These are the table create scripts:

```
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Order`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Order` (
  `order_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `verznr` INT NOT NULL,
  `datum` DATE NOT NULL,
  `status` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `huisarts` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `apotheker` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`order_id`, `verznr`, `huisarts`, `apotheker`),
  INDEX `order_huisarts_idx` (`huisarts` ASC),
  INDEX `order_apotheker_idx` (`apotheker` ASC)
  )
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Patient`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Patient` (
  `verznr` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `achternaam` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `geboorteplaats` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `adres` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `tel` INT(4) NOT NULL,
  `postcode` VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
  `apotheker` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `huisarts` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `post` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `idenid` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`verznr`, `huisarts`, `apotheker`),
  CONSTRAINT `pat_order`
    FOREIGN KEY (`verznr`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Order` (`verznr`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
    ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

This is created as a model in mysql workbench and then exported into an sql create script. For some reason it gives me an error with the foreign key from Patient to Order. I've narrowed it down to that. In both tables `verznr` are INT not null and primary keys. When the foreign key is made it doesn't work though.

Comment: What fields are you applying the foreign key on?

Comment: It's from `patienten`.`verznr` to `order`.`verznr`. the foreign key that's not working is called `pat_order`